# Как сделать выборку svg для mimetype?

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

[image: one]
[image: two]

Wordpress.
Не могу понять, как выводить svg из папки, которые будут равны mimetype документов.
Мне не нужен плагин, хотел бы чистый php увидеть.
Причем суть в том, что каждый файл подписан под определенный mimetype и соответственно выборка будет чисто от "%exel%.svg = application/%exel" ?

Comment: Код должен быть текстом прямо в вопросе. Картинка - картинкой, а не ссылкой.

Comment: Исправил ссылки

Comment: у вас даже в mime нету svg ...

Comment: @MaximLensky Уже решил проблему и дело даже не в указаной директории. Я не знал, как логически это все написать и попросил помощи. Да и как минимум туда svg не вставляется.

Comment: Код текстом пиши, а не картинками!